# Xamarin Black Splash Screen

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I tried to make a new storyboard Splash Screen on my Mac, but when I exported it from Xcode to my app project on Windows Visual Studio, the app didn't work. I had a black screen when starting the debug session on my simulator. I backed up the previous storyboard code in order it won't work but it didn't work with the original one either..

Comment: Did you try to add `storyboard ` in VS for mac  and open with Xcode ? Then you can copy the storyboard file to Windows Visual Studio .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that told me to edit the info.plist and remove those lines:

```
<key>UIApplicationSceneManifest</key>
 <dict>
     <key>UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes</key>
     <true/>
 </dict>
```

And it worked for me :)